# Error: The type com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package is not visible

Tags: java, file, types

I have this error in my code when I tried  to create a program to read directories and its content.

> The type com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package is not visible

My code is simple for now:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package exercice5;

import com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package.File;

/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class ListFilesAndDirectories {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public ListFilesAndDirectories() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myfile = new File(".");
    }

}
```

I do not understand where the problem is since I think that I have imported the right `File` package.

Does someone understand this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your import is wrong. Replace

```
import com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package.File;
```

with

```
import java.io.File;
```

Comment: Ok with that import its working, but I do not why eclipse proposed me that import

Comment: @H.DJEMAI Eclipse proposed it because this class exists (it is an internal class of package-protected class `com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package`) but this suggestion is not very clever. I hope that it was not the first autocompletion suggestion.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle In my case, it was the only one autocompletion suggestion. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It says Package class is not public, see decompiled version:

```
class com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package {
...
```